# How to use putExtra() with FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT in Android Apps?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application, call "App1". In my App1 I invoke Camera application.

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.camera","com.android.camera.Camera"));
startActivity(intent);
```

After that, I use FileObserver to listen whether user take a photo. When this happens I call

```
Context ctx = App1.this.getApplicationContext();
Intent j = new Intent(ctx, App1.class);
j.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
j.putExtra("type", 1);
startActivity(j);
```

It works, I mean it gets my application to front how I leave it, however I need to pass an integer, which is called "type". I think, my application will call "onResume()" but how can I get that extra integer. This type of passing didn't do anything in my application.

There's Bundle savedInstanceState in onCreate method, but there is no such a thing in onResume method. So, I need your help to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to override [Activity.onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) method.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

After `onNewIntent()` is called, the normal `onResume()` lifecycle will follow. Alternatively, you can write your code in `onNewIntent()` itself.

Comment: Its mentioned that  FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP will call the onNewIntent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT will too call the onNewIntent?

Comment: @mahemadhi Even if the documentation does not mention it I observed that, yes this method is called when you use the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT with a modified Intent.