# Passing data between two running activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I need to pass data from one activity to another. The first time, there is no problem because a new intent is created. My problem is that I use the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, because I don't want to destroy the activity since I don't want to go into onCreate every time I switch activity. My question is, how can I pass an array from two running activities?

I am creating a game in android studio, that is similar to Yatzy. In one activity you roll the dices and in the other, you set the score in a scoreboard. Every time the player is navigated to the scoreboard, all possible results are shown, except for the ones that are already chosen (on these places you see the chosen results), and the player can then chose a score, for example, "full house". When I navigate between the two activities I do not want to destroy them since they contain information that I don't want to reset. Therefore I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, but when I use this the new combinations of the dices are not shown, it only shows the first combination of dices.

Here is when I pass the data from MainActivity:

```
Intent openMainActivity= new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScoreboardActivity.class);
openMainActivity.putExtra("scoreList", game.showScoreAlt());
openMainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT));
startActivity(openMainActivity)
```

Here is when I receive the data in the other activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
scoreList = extras.getIntArray("scoreList");
```

Comment: What do you mean by passing data between running activities? The code you provided should be working fine.

Comment: `When I navigate between the two activities I do not want to destroy them since they contain information that I don't want to reset` use onSavedInstance to temporarily store data to disk in case the Activity is destroyed when the user has low RAM. please note that it's impossible to prevent an activity from being destroyed. Your app will be removed from RAM eventually. You can however persist data and restore that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this **Activity.onNewIntent()** method.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7175308/4517450).

Comment: great, please accept as an answer so it help others also